# Pandas Pivot Tables is empty, want to fill with values from other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a table which e.g. looks like this

| Food | Compound | Content in grams |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kiwi | Fat | 5 |
| Kiwi | Protein | 3 |
| Apple | Protein | 2 |

I want to pivot it with pandas, so that it looks like

| Food | Fat | Protein |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kiwi | 5 | 3 |
| Apple | 2 | 0 |

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: **Reproducing the problem:**
`df = pd.DataFrame({"Food":["Kiwi","Kiwi","Apple"], "Compound":["Fat","Protein","Protein"], "Content in grams":[5,3,2]})`  

**Pivoting:**  

`df.pivot(index = 'Food', columns='Compound',values='Content in grams').reset_index()`